# saving an RDD inside a specific directory

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, rdd

How to save an rdd inside of a specific directory in hdfs? `rdd.saveAsTextFile()` saves into a new file but I want to save it inside a given directory. How can that be done? Thanks

Comment: what is the confusion ? Does `saveAsTextFile ` not take an argument with directory path ?

Comment: say if I want to create new files in directory x, I wrote, rdd.saveasTextFile("hdfs:master:54310/x/y"). It creates a new file in "/" directory.

Comment: The path should be on a local file system, not on HDFS

Comment: what if I want to save it to hdfs?

Comment: you would just do `df.write.csv("outfile.csv")`